A confusion about $SU(2)$ group
I was reading the basic properties about $SU(2)$ group. As the fundamental representation, $SU(2)$ matrices operate on two-dimensional vector
$$
\eta=\begin{pmatrix}\eta_1 \\\eta_2\end{pmatrix}.
$$
The general transformation matrix of $SU(2)$ can be written as
$$
\hat{U}=\begin{pmatrix}a &b \\-b^* &a^*\end{pmatrix}\,,\qquad\tilde{\eta}=\hat{U}\eta.
$$
I was told that $\eta$ and $\eta^\dagger$ transform in a different way under $SU(2)$. It is easy to understand since
$$
\tilde{\eta}=\hat{U}\eta\,,\qquad\tilde{\eta}^\dagger=\tilde{\eta}^\dagger\hat{U}^\dagger.
$$
However, it is confused to be told that
$$
\begin{pmatrix}\eta_1 \\\eta_2\end{pmatrix}\,,\qquad \begin{pmatrix}-\eta^*_2 \\\eta^*_1\end{pmatrix}
$$
transform in the same way. My question is what is the meaning of this sentence?

Hint: when $\hat U$ is unitary, so is $\hat U ^*$.

First, let me mention that a matrix of the form
$$
U=\begin{pmatrix}a &b \\-b^* &a^*\end{pmatrix}$$
is only an element of $\operatorname{SU}(2)$ if $\det U = 1$. With that being said, let's look at your question:
Let $U=\begin{pmatrix}a &b \\-b^* &a^*\end{pmatrix} \in \operatorname{SU}(2)$.
Consider first
$$
\begin{pmatrix} \tilde \eta_1 \\ \tilde \eta_2\end{pmatrix}
:=  U \cdot \begin{pmatrix}  \eta_1 \\  \eta_2\end{pmatrix}
= \left(\begin{matrix}
a\eta_1+b\eta_2 \\
\eta_2 a^*-\eta_1 b^*
\end{matrix}\right)\,.
$$
Now consider
$$
\begin{pmatrix} -\tilde \eta_2^* \\ \tilde \eta_1^*\end{pmatrix}
:=  U \cdot \begin{pmatrix} -\eta_2^* \\\eta_1^*\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}
b \eta_1^* - a \eta_2^*\\
a^* \eta_1^* + b^* \eta_2^*
\end{pmatrix}\,.
$$
It is easy to see that the resulting transformations for $\eta_1, \eta_2, \eta_1^*, \eta_2^*$ are consistent with each other. In this sense, one can say that
$\begin{pmatrix} \eta_1 \\ \eta_2 \end{pmatrix}
$ and $\begin{pmatrix} -\eta_2^* \\\eta_1^*\end{pmatrix}$ transform in the same way.

The sentence introduces the celebrated conjugate representation of SU(2), the very linchpin of fermion masses for both members of chiral doublets in a generation of the SM.
Defining
$$
\theta\equiv -i\sigma_2 \eta^*,
$$
you have
$$
\eta\mapsto \hat U \eta, \implies \eta^*\mapsto \hat U^* \eta^* , \implies \\
 \theta \mapsto -i\sigma_2 \hat U^* (i\sigma_2) \theta= \hat U \theta. 
$$
